# VB.net get date from string

Tags: vba, excel

Can you help me to extract date from string/text

Let say I have this following strings

1. `"This is a date, January 23, 2016 Stackoverflow!"`
2. `"this 27 Aug 16 is in date format."`
3. `"03.22.2017 is also a date."`

and the output I need is this.

1. `January 23, 2016`
2. `27 Aug 16`
3. `03.22.2017`

basically all I need in the text is the date only.
Please help. Thanks

Comment: Are you going to use VB.NET or VBA? These are 2 completely different languages. Please clarify in your tags. Also this is no free code writing service therefore you should show what you have tried so far. This link might be helpful: [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) in combination with a pattern like this: https://regex101.com/r/mBk1YI/1 Probably give it a try and if you got stuck come back with your code and your question to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Pᴇʜ Regex pattern shared in the comment works perfectly per your examples. Here is how to use it with an in cell function.

**Don't Forget** to add the reference to "*Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5*"

```
Function simpleCellRegex(Myrange As Range) As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim matches As Object

    strPattern = "(?:January|Februrary|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) [0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{4}|[0-9]{1,2} (?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) [0-9]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{2,4}"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Myrange.Value

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            Set matches = regEx.Execute(strInput)
            If matches.Count <> 0 Then simpleCellRegex = matches.Item(0)
        Else
            simpleCellRegex = "Not matched"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

---

Input is in column A and column B uses formula `=simpleCellRegex(A1)`

**Tested**

[image]